# Android HTML5 Widgets in WebView

Tags: android, html, iframe, android-webview

Basically, I want to display a Soundcloud HTML5 widget on a WebView.

One of these things:
[image]

I have the embed code given by the widget itself:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/34019569&amp;color=0066cc"></iframe>
```

Calling `webView.loadUrl(embedHTML);` yields a blank WebView. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you show the value of 'embedHTML' ? If it's a link, can you show the full html of the page ?

Comment: Sorry, embedHTML is the "embed code" shown above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation for WebView :

*void loadUrl (String url)* :
Loads the given URL.

embedHTML is not a url but the content of a webpage, what you want is to load the data. WebView has a dedicated method for this :

*void loadData (String data, 
                String mimeType, 
                String encoding)*

In your case it would look like this :

```
String data = "<html><body><iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/34019569&amp;color=0066cc"></iframe></body></html>";
webview.loadData(data, "text/html", null);
```

You might have to play with the formating of your embedHTML so that JAVA accept it as a String.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't wrap my `<iframe>` with `<html>` and `<body>` tags...A day in the life of a novice developer!